# How can I return all the columns of a table using multiple distinct columns in Linq

Tags: linq

How can I return all the columns of a table using multiple distinct columns in linq. I need to return all columns of a table with multiple distincts?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are trying to do? Show a couple of sample rows from a real or sample table. Then describe the data you want to retrieve from that table.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use GroupBy:

```
var distinctModelYears = cars.GroupBy(c => new { c.Year, c.Model })
                             .Select(g => g.First()) //Take one from each group
                             ;
```

That will find all "distinct" years and models so there will only be one 2008 Accord, one 2009 Accord, etc.

Comment: Taking the above example, say I have columns like Year, Model and Make. I need to return all the columns (Year, Model and Make) Group by Year and Model. So, combination of Year and Model will be unique.